# I'm not able to read and format the json into a dataframe

Tags: r, json, dataframe, census

I was able to run the following code without error about a year ago, but am getting an error message now:

Here's the code:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
library(xlsx)

setwd("C:\\Users\\MUSTAFA.ZIA\\Desktop\\R Projects\\Excel Table\\")

key <- "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" # My Census Key 
#                                             ***************
                                              
year = 2021 # Update this YEAR value to get the latest data file available
#            *************************************************************

# Here we read the API and convert it into  data frame simultaneously 
#********************************************************************

export_API <-as.data.frame(fromJSON(paste0("https://api.census.gov/data/timeseries/intltrade/exports/hs?get=ALL_VAL_YR,ALL_VAL_MO,E_COMMODITY,E_COMMODITY_SDESC,E_COMMODITY_LDESC,MONTH,QTY_1_YR,UNIT_QY1&YEAR=",year,"")))
```

Here's the error that I'm getting:

```
Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : 
  lexical error: invalid character inside string.
          F ANY OTHER SINGLE FRUIT, NUT OR VEG, UNFERMENTED AND NOT C
                     (right here) ------^
```

I checked online and it mentions that the error occurs when what's read is not json, but the census international trade data file is definitely a json file per their documentation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There seem to be some invalid characters in the JSON file. When I open it in Firefox, it says "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal at line 55849 column 123 of the JSON data". When downloading it in R with `readLines`, I see "NUT \032OR VEG," there.

Answer (score 1):

Please keep your examples as short as possible; only include what's necessary to reproduce the error:

```
library(jsonlite)

year = 2021 # Update this YEAR value to get the latest data file available

export_API <-as.data.frame(fromJSON(paste0("https://api.census.gov/data/timeseries/intltrade/exports/hs?get=ALL_VAL_YR,ALL_VAL_MO,E_COMMODITY,E_COMMODITY_SDESC,E_COMMODITY_LDESC,MONTH,QTY_1_YR,UNIT_QY1&YEAR=",year,"")))
```

or even just:

```
jsonlite::fromJSON("https://api.census.gov/data/timeseries/intltrade/exports/hs?get=ALL_VAL_YR,ALL_VAL_MO,E_COMMODITY,E_COMMODITY_SDESC,E_COMMODITY_LDESC,MONTH,QTY_1_YR,UNIT_QY1&YEAR=2021")
```

---

As can be seen in the comment by @Robert Hacken, there's (at least one) stray control character in your source: [\032 aka \x1a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character) (their line numbers change though). According to the JSON specifications, these [should have been escaped](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159#section-7), but they aren't. This triggers an error in the JSON import functions.

It would be proper to notify the US Census about this issue. But until they fix the issue, we can create a workaround:

I have made the following function that replaces or escapes control characters in a character vector:

```
# sub_control_chars()
#
# substitutes control characters in a string
# control characters: \x00 through \x1F plus \x7F
#
# replace: replacement string
# escape:  if TRUE: escape the control character instead of replacing
# warn:    if TRUE: give a warning() for every replacement/escape

sub_control_chars <- function(x, allow = c('\t','\n'), replace = '�', escape = FALSE, warn = TRUE, context = 20) {
  
  # function definitions
  print2string <- function(str) { str <- capture.output(print(str, quote=F)); substr(str, 5, nchar(str)) }
  
  str_context <- function() {
    context_str <- paste0(ifelse(i-context > 0, '…', '"'),
                          print2string(substr(x, i-context, i+context)),
                          ifelse(i+context < nchar(x), '…', '"'))
    precontext_length <- nchar(print2string(substr(x, i-context, i-1)))
    char_length <- nchar(print2string(substr(x, i, i)))
    paste0('Location: ', context_str, '\n', strrep(' ',precontext_length + 11), strrep('^',char_length), '\n')
  }
  
  # reference: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dd/ASCII-Table.svg
  SPACE <- as.raw(0x20)
  DEL   <- as.raw(0x7F)
  
  # find index of characters of interest
  raw <- charToRaw(x)
  indices <- which(raw < SPACE | raw == DEL)
  
  # iterate over characters of interest
  for(ii in seq_along(indices)) {
    
    i <- indices[ii]
    
    char <- substr(x, i, i)
    
    if(char %in% allow) next
    
    if(warn) warning('Character: 0x',charToRaw(char),' at position ',i,'\n',str_context(), call.=F, immediate.=T)
    
    if(isFALSE(escape)) newchar <- replace else newchar <- paste0(escape,charToRaw(char))
    x <- paste0( substr(x, 1, i-1), newchar, substr(x, i+1, nchar(x)) )
    indices <- indices + nchar(newchar) - 1
    
  }

  return(x)
  
}
```

Since this doesn't handle URLs as input, we first need to download the (broken) JSON and read it into a vector before we can process it.

Since the faulty characters are useless to use, I've chosen to remove them (replace = '') rather than escape them or replace them with a placeholder:

```
library(jsonlite)
year = 2021 # Update this YEAR value to get the latest data file available


# download URL to a character vector --------------------------------------

json.url <- paste0("https://api.census.gov/data/timeseries/intltrade/exports/hs?get=ALL_VAL_YR,ALL_VAL_MO,E_COMMODITY,E_COMMODITY_SDESC,E_COMMODITY_LDESC,MONTH,QTY_1_YR,UNIT_QY1&YEAR=",year)

options(timeout=max(300, getOption("timeout"))) # increase timeout to 5 minutes because this large query takes a lot of time!
json.file <- tempfile()
download.file(json.url, json.file) # download url to temporary file
json.raw <- readr::read_file(json.file) # read file into vector


# repair file -------------------------------------------------------------

# remove control characters
json.fixed <- sub_control_chars(json.raw, replace='')


# read repaired JSON from vector ------------------------------------------

export_API <- as.data.frame(fromJSON(json.fixed))
```

Running `sub_control_chars()` will give 12 'warnings' that an invalid character has been replaced, and the resulting JSON can be loaded without any issues.

Comment: I thought of a solution to skip or replace the character but I don't know R well enough to have come up with a solution ....Thank you good sir!